# Prestashop 1.7 translation duplicate entry

Tags: prestashop, translation, ps, prestashop-1.7

Adding more than one translation field to the same theme and same module would create a duplication error.

This is the errror:

> app.ERROR: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO
>   ps_translation (`key`, translation, domain, theme, id_lang) VALUES (?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["Reviews", "Avis", "ShopThemeCatalog",
>   "chateau", 1]:  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>   1062 Duplicate entry 'chateau-1-ShopThemeCatalog' for key
>   'theme' [] []

How can I add one more translation in the same theme and in the same module ?

Answer (score 0):

Just used different Translation Domain Name. 
Such as now its use this for one text  `shop.theme.catalog`
you can use  another `shop.theme.front` or any others.